# How do you insert an image using Report Lab's canvas drawImage()?

Tags: python, pdf-generation, reportlab, drawimage

I'm looking to expand the functionality of a tool using report lab's pdfgen which currently only draws strings using;

```
if json_data[definition["field"]] != "":
    c.drawString(
        definition["x"] * cm,
        definition["y"] * cm,
        json_data[definition["field"]]
)
```

and the json;

```
{
    "field":"name",
    "x":1.8,
    "y":10
},
```

So to draw images instead of strings I did the following;

```
if json_data[definition["field"]] != "":
    if definition.has_key("image"):
        c.drawImage(
            os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "images", "successIcon.gif"),
            definition["x"] * cm,
            definition["y"] * cm,
            width=16, height=16,
        )
    else:
        c.drawString(
            definition["x"] * cm,
            definition["y"] * cm,
            json_data[definition["field"]]
)
```

with the json updated to;

```
{
    "field":"name",
    "x":1.8,
    "y":10,
    "image":"name"
},
```

Is there something wrong with that call to `drawImage`? It looks correct according to the docs but it doesn't make it to `drawImage` because I've tried to log the args which the function gets & I'm getting nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There wasn't anything wrong with the method I used to use `drawImage` and the following code is currently in use successfully;

```
# If we have an image attribute
if definition.has_key("image"):
    if str(json_data[definition["field"]]) == 'True':
        # need to replace this with url on attribute
        filename = os.path.join(
            os.getcwd(),
            "static",
            "images",
            definition["image"]
        )
        c.drawImage(filename, definition["x"] * cm, definition["y"] * cm, 10, -10)
```

And the corresponding json to specify the image filename;

```
{
    "field":"name",
    "x":1.66,
    "y":19.45,
    "image":"image.jpg"
},
```